# Clang++ Xcode 4.4 Non Static Member Initialization and Move constructor

Tags: c++, xcode, c++11, clang, member-initialization

I am using Xcode 4.4 with mountain lion. I can't seems to understand why non-static member initalization in templates invokes a move constructor for the variable. Is there anyway to overcome this error?

Example Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <atomic>

//
// This class can compile
//
class Working
{
public:
    int GetValue() { return value_; }

private:
    std::atomic<int> value_{0};
};

//
// This class cannot compile
//
template <typename Ty1>
class NotWorking
{
public:
    int GetValue() { return value_; }

    private:
        std::atomic<int> value_{0}; // <---- error here
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    Working working;
    NotWorking<int> not_working;

    return 0;
}
```

Xcode 4.4 and Clang throws the error in that line saying:

```
"Copying member subobject of type 'std::atomic<int>' invokes deleted constructor"
```

Comment: I don't think this can be anything _other_ than a compiler bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a clang bug on the open source svn trunk repository.  Could you submit a bug report against clang [here](http://llvm.org/bugs/):  http://llvm.org/bugs/ ?

Thanks!